# Changing font breaks Windows 11 search

Tags: windows, windows-11, font

Migrated one of my PC from Windows 10 to 11 (23H2 22631.2861).

After the migration, I noticed that the search feature did not work anymore :

- Nothing happens when I clic on the search icon on the task bar
- Weird start menu UI freeze when I clic on the search bar in the start menu panel

I tried many candidate solutions ("sfc /scannow", "dsim ...", restarts, Windows updates, many powershell scripts, rebuild the search index, etc). Nothing worked.

I finally found out the cause. It simply comes from the age old and quite known custom regedit file that we can use to replace the "Windows font" (the one used in explorer windows), for example described in https://www.lifewire.com/change-font-windows-11-6827640. I used Tahoma font, but it should not be relevant.

I've been using this for years, over several Windows versions. But both my Windows 11 PC do not like it.

So, is this a known issue? How can I change my Windows font without breaking the Windows search?